# Generate group key by one identifier in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas, numpy

I'm new in python, I wonder can I generate group key by only one column of identifier. Such as I have the input file like

```
inv_id  GROUP
511031  Y
204501  Y
105756  N
134092  N
591688  N
235318  Y
642085  Y
134390  Y
211797  N
456165  N
556364  Y
169807  Y
406002  N
266034  N
313153  N
42474   Y
102622  Y
```

The expected output I wanted to get is

```
inv_id  GROUP   GROUP_ID
511031  Y       001
204501  Y       001
105756  N       002
134092  N       003
591688  N       004
235318  Y       005
642085  Y       005
134390  Y       005
211797  N       006
456165  N       007
556364  Y       008
169807  Y       008
406002  N       009
266034  N       010
313153  N       011
42474   Y       012
102622  Y       012
```

If "GROUP" column 'Y' is standing in row so it have be the same group and GROUP_ID have to be write, If "GROUP" column is 'N' then generate continues id.

I want to get some example python code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way using a Boolean mask and [`pd.Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html).

```
mask1 = df['GROUP'] == 'N'
mask2 = (df['GROUP'] == 'Y') & (df['GROUP'].shift() == 'N')

df['GROUP_ID'] = ((mask1 | mask2).cumsum() + 1).astype(str).str.zfill(3)

print(df)

    inv_id GROUP GROUP_ID
0   511031     Y      001
1   204501     Y      001
2   105756     N      002
3   134092     N      003
4   591688     N      004
5   235318     Y      005
6   642085     Y      005
7   134390     Y      005
8   211797     N      006
9   456165     N      007
10  556364     Y      008
11  169807     Y      008
12  406002     N      009
13  266034     N      010
14  313153     N      011
15   42474     Y      012
16  102622     Y      012
```